# I want to add the alt attribute to all the photos!

Tags: functions, code

Hello everyone and I found you well, I have a problem with a dynamic site that contains over 200,000 photos, it is a news site. The site is built on the WordPress platform and has many changes to suit our business. In vain I complete the attribute alt for each photo he does not appear live. After many consultations a code must be added to the code attached to this post. My question is, what code should be added and where in this file?
If anyone can help me I would be grateful, thank you!

```
<?php
class home_main_post_below_list extends AQ_Block {
    //set and create block
    function __construct() {
        $block_options = array(
            'name' => 'Home main post with below list post',
            'size' => 'span12',
        );

        //create the block
        parent::__construct('home_main_post_below_list', $block_options);
    }
    //create form
    function form($instance) {
        $titles = isset($instance['titles']) ? esc_attr($instance['titles']) : 'Recent Posts';
        $number_show = isset($instance['number_show']) ? absint($instance['number_show']) : 5;
        ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titles'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'tl_back'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titles'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('titles'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $titles; ?>" /></p>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number_show'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts to show:', 'tl_back'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number_show'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number_show'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number_show; ?>" size="3" /></p>

            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cats'); ?>"><?php _e('Select categories to include in the recent posts list:', 'tl_back'); ?> 

                <?php
                $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
                echo "<br/>";
                foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                    $option = '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id('cats') . '[]" name="' . $this->get_field_name('cats') . '[]"';
                    if (isset($instance['cats'])) {
                        foreach ($instance['cats'] as $cats) {
                            if ($cats == $cat->term_id) {
                                $option = $option . ' checked="checked"';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $option .= ' value="' . $cat->term_id . '" />';
                    $option .= '&nbsp;';
                    $option .= $cat->cat_name;
                    $option .= '<br />';
                    echo $option;
                }
                ?>
            </label>    
        <?php

    }

    //create block
    function block($instance) {

            extract($instance);

        $titles = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['titles']) ? 'Recent Posts' : $instance['titles'], $instance, $this->id_base);


                if (!isset($instance["cats"])) {
            $cats = '';}

        // array to call recent posts.

        $themeloy_args = array(
            'showposts' => $number_show,
            'category__in' => $cats,
        );

        $themeloy_widget = null;
        $themeloy_widget = new WP_Query($themeloy_args);

        ?>
        <div class="widget post_list_medium_widget">
        <?php if (!empty($instance['titles'])) {?><h3 class="widget-title"><span><?php echo $instance["titles"];?></span></h3><?php }?>
        <div class="widget_container">
        <div class="post_list_medium">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        while ($themeloy_widget->have_posts()) {
           $i++;
           $themeloy_widget->the_post();
           $post_id = get_the_ID();
           $thumb = themeloy_get_thumbnail(get_the_ID());
            if ($i == 1) {          
                ?>   

                 <div class="list_item">

                    <div class="entry-thumb feature-item"> 
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'feature-large' );
    ?>
    <img class="cat-feature-large-img" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"/>
<?php }else{echo '<img class="cat-feature-large-img" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/demo/feature-large.jpg'.'">';} ?>
                    </a>

                    <div class="cat-feature-large">
                    <?php $post_cat = get_post_custom_values('cat_themeloy_select', get_the_ID());
         $post_cat = ($post_cat[0] != '') ? $post_cat[0] : of_get_option('blog_category_post');
         if($post_cat == '1'){echo '<p class="cat-slider">'; echo the_category(', ').'</p>';}?>
         </div>

                    <?php echo themeloy_post_type(); ?>
                    </div>
                 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php echo themeloy_post_meta(get_the_ID());?>
    <p><?php echo themeloy_short_title(320, get_the_excerpt('')); ?>  </p>
    </div>
     <div class="clear margin-buttons"></div>
                <?php }else{?>                  

                <div class="small-list-content">
            <?php
                                    $post_date = get_post_custom_values('date_themeloy_select', get_the_ID()); 
                                    $post_date = ($post_date[0] != '') ? $post_date[0] : of_get_option('blog_date_post');
                                 if($post_date == '1'){
     ?>
     <div class="feature_post_style">
                        <span class="post_date"><span class="date_number"><?php echo get_the_date('d');?></span> <?php echo get_the_date('M');?>
                        <i class="icon-caret-right feature-icon-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="post_time"><i class="icon-time"></i> <?php echo get_the_time('H:i');?></span>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                        <div class="feature-link feature-item">             
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="feature-link">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'medium-feature' );
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"/>
<?php }else{echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/demo/medium-feature.jpg'.'">';} ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php echo themeloy_post_type(); ?>
                        </div>

                       <div class="list_desc">
                           <h4 class="list_title"><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a></h4>

                   <?php echo themeloy_post_meta(get_the_ID());?>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>                     
</div>

                <?php }}?>


      </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        wp_reset_query();   

    }

        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        return $new_instance;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your current code manages all blocks with images replacing usage `wp_get_attachment_image_src` with output of hardcoded `img` tag, with `echo wp_get_attachment_image()` which will return `img` tag as string with default alt of image or empty if non set will work.

Below is your code updated with idea described.

```
<?php
class home_main_post_below_list extends AQ_Block {
    //set and create block
    function __construct() {
        $block_options = array(
            'name' => 'Home main post with below list post',
            'size' => 'span12',
        );

        //create the block
        parent::__construct('home_main_post_below_list', $block_options);
    }
    //create form
    function form($instance) {
        $titles = isset($instance['titles']) ? esc_attr($instance['titles']) : 'Recent Posts';
        $number_show = isset($instance['number_show']) ? absint($instance['number_show']) : 5;
        ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titles'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'tl_back'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titles'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('titles'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $titles; ?>" /></p>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number_show'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts to show:', 'tl_back'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number_show'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number_show'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number_show; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cats'); ?>"><?php _e('Select categories to include in the recent posts list:', 'tl_back'); ?>

            <?php
            $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
            echo "<br/>";
            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                $option = '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id('cats') . '[]" name="' . $this->get_field_name('cats') . '[]"';
                if (isset($instance['cats'])) {
                    foreach ($instance['cats'] as $cats) {
                        if ($cats == $cat->term_id) {
                            $option = $option . ' checked="checked"';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $option .= ' value="' . $cat->term_id . '" />';
                $option .= '&nbsp;';
                $option .= $cat->cat_name;
                $option .= '<br />';
                echo $option;
            }
            ?>
        </label>
        <?php

    }

    //create block
    function block($instance) {

        extract($instance);

        $titles = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['titles']) ? 'Recent Posts' : $instance['titles'], $instance, $this->id_base);


        if (!isset($instance["cats"])) {
            $cats = '';}

        // array to call recent posts.

        $themeloy_args = array(
            'showposts' => $number_show,
            'category__in' => $cats,
        );

        $themeloy_widget = null;
        $themeloy_widget = new WP_Query($themeloy_args);

        ?>
        <div class="widget post_list_medium_widget">
            <?php if (!empty($instance['titles'])) {?><h3 class="widget-title"><span><?php echo $instance["titles"];?></span></h3><?php }?>
            <div class="widget_container">
                <div class="post_list_medium">
                    <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    while ($themeloy_widget->have_posts()) {
                        $i++;
                        $themeloy_widget->the_post();
                        $post_id = get_the_ID();
                        $thumb = themeloy_get_thumbnail(get_the_ID());
                        if ($i == 1) {
                            ?>

                            <div class="list_item">

                                <div class="entry-thumb feature-item">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'feature-large', false, array('class'=>'cat-feature-large-img') );
                                        } else {echo '<img class="cat-feature-large-img" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/demo/feature-large.jpg'.'" alt="">';} ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <div class="cat-feature-large">
                                        <?php $post_cat = get_post_custom_values('cat_themeloy_select', get_the_ID());
                                        $post_cat = ($post_cat[0] != '') ? $post_cat[0] : of_get_option('blog_category_post');
                                        if($post_cat == '1'){echo '<p class="cat-slider">'; echo the_category(', ').'</p>';}?>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php echo themeloy_post_type(); ?>
                                </div>
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                                <?php echo themeloy_post_meta(get_the_ID());?>
                                <p><?php echo themeloy_short_title(320, get_the_excerpt('')); ?>  </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear margin-buttons"></div>
                        <?php }else{?>

                            <div class="small-list-content">
                                <?php
                                $post_date = get_post_custom_values('date_themeloy_select', get_the_ID());
                                $post_date = ($post_date[0] != '') ? $post_date[0] : of_get_option('blog_date_post');
                                if($post_date == '1'){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="feature_post_style">
                        <span class="post_date"><span class="date_number"><?php echo get_the_date('d');?></span> <?php echo get_the_date('M');?>
                        <i class="icon-caret-right feature-icon-right"></i>
                        </span>
                                        <span class="post_time"><i class="icon-time"></i> <?php echo get_the_time('H:i');?></span>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }?>
                                <div class="feature-link feature-item">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="feature-link">
                                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'medium-feature', false );
                                        }else{echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/demo/medium-feature.jpg" alt="">';} ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php echo themeloy_post_type(); ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="list_desc">
                                    <h4 class="list_title"><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </a></h4>

                                    <?php echo themeloy_post_meta(get_the_ID());?>

                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>

                        <?php }}?>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        wp_reset_query();

    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        return $new_instance;
    }


}
```

Also fallback `img` tags if none post_thumbnail set got `alt` attribute empty as it's required by accessibility guidelines.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer, I put the updated code but do not let me save it give error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'  How can I fix this error Mikhail ?

Comment: Hi @fantomas17, yes there was a typo error. now fixed. please copy updated snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

And here I have the same problem, can you implement that other code in this code as well?

```
<?php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'themeloy_rec_register_widgets' );

function themeloy_rec_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'themeloy_rec_posts_widget' );
}

class themeloy_rec_posts_widget extends WP_Widget {


    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname'   => 'post_list_widget', 
            'description' => __('Display a list of recent post entries from choosing categories.', 'tl_back')
        );
        parent::__construct('rec-recent-posts', __('Themeloy: Recently Posts', 'tl_back'), $widget_ops);
    }



    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? 'Recently Articles' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);
        if (!$number = absint($instance['number']))
            $number = 6;
        if (!$cats = $instance["cats"])
            $cats = '';


        $post_cat_args = array(
            'showposts' => $number,
            'category__in' => $cats,
        );

        $post_cat_widget = null;
        $post_cat_widget = new WP_Query($post_cat_args);


        echo $before_widget;


        echo $before_title;
        echo $instance["title"];
        echo $after_title;

        // Post list in widget
        echo '<div class="widget_container">';
        echo '<ul class="post_list">';

        while ($post_cat_widget->have_posts()) {
            $post_cat_widget->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            ?>
           <li class="clearfix">    
                <div class="img_thumbnail feature-item">
                <?php               
                echo '<a class="img_thumbnail" href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">';?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'small-feature' );?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
<?php }else{echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/demo/small-feature.jpg'.'">';} ?>   

              </a>
              <?php echo themeloy_post_type(); ?>
         </div>
                <div class="list_desc">
                     <h4 class="list_title"><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a></h4>
                   <?php echo themeloy_post_meta(get_the_ID());?>
                            <?php 
                                $post_review = get_post_custom_values('enable_review_themeloy_select', $post_id); 
                                $post_review = ($post_review[0] != '') ? $post_review[0] : of_get_option('enable_all_review');
                                $total_review = absint(themeloy_get_total_review($post_id));
                                if($post_review == '1'){
                               ?>
<div class="ratings">
<div class="rating-box">
<div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo themeloy_get_total_review(get_the_ID()); ?>%"></div>
</div>
</div>
 <?php }?> 

                </div>


            </li>
            <?php
        }

        wp_reset_query();

        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo $after_widget;
    }



    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['cats'] = $new_instance['cats'];
        $instance['number'] = absint($new_instance['number']);

        return $instance;
    }



    function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset($instance['title']) ? esc_attr($instance['title']) : 'Recent Posts';
        $number = isset($instance['number']) ? absint($instance['number']) : 5;

?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'tl_back'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts to show:', 'tl_back'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

         <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cats'); ?>"><?php _e('Select categories to include in the recent posts list:', 'tl_back');?> 

                <?php
                   $categories=  get_categories('hide_empty=0');
                     echo "<br/>";
                     foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                    $option = '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id('cats') . '[]" name="' . $this->get_field_name('cats') . '[]"';

                    if (isset($instance['cats'])) {
                        foreach ($instance['cats'] as $cats) {
                            if ($cats == $cat->term_id) {
                                $option = $option . ' checked="checked"';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $option .= ' value="' . $cat->term_id . '" />';
                    $option .= '&nbsp;';
                    $option .= $cat->cat_name;
                    $option .= '<br />';
                    echo $option;
                }

                    ?>
            </label>
        </p>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks!